# Split a very large SQL table to multiple smaller tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, export

Is it possible to search a column within a table for a numerical value range of 1-2000 and then copy each full row into a different table? By doing so technically splitting the table into smaller parts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64589/discussion-on-question-by-sarge-split-a-very-large-sql-table-to-multiple-smaller).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addressing the question behind the question:

> Maybe you can answer this. Is it possible to search a column within a table for a numerical value range of 1-2000 and then copy each full row into a different table?

If you already have a column by which you can "partition" the table, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
 INTO dbo.newtable_0001_to_2000 
 FROM dbo.existingtable 
 WHERE column >= 1 AND column <= 2000;

SELECT * 
 INTO dbo.newtable_2001_to_4000 
 FROM dbo.existingtable 
 WHERE column >= 2001 AND column <= 4000;

...
```

Just note that this will give you a predictable number of rows, but won't control the *size* of the rows, so depending on the data in each "partition" these tables will not likely be of equal sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column with a unique row number by using the row_number() function:

```
  SELECT    LINKRECID ,
            FLAGS ,
            USERID ,
            FOLDER ,
            FOLDER2 ,
            ACCOUNTNO ,
            CREATEON ,
            MAILSIZE ,
            MAILDATE ,
            MAILTIME ,
            MAILREF ,
            LOPRECID ,
            RFC822_Old ,
            RECID ,
            MAILID ,
            EXT ,
            RFC822 ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LINKRECID, FLAGS, USERID, FOLDER, FOLDER2, ACCOUNTNO, CREATEON, MAILSIZE, MAILDATE, MAILTIME, MAILREF, LOPRECID, RFC822_Old, RECID, MAILID, EXT, RFC822 ) AS RowNum
```

However, I strongly agree with Aaron Bertrand that you are creating inefficiencies, possibly on a massive scale.  SQL is much better at searching/filtering data than Excel.  You should, at the very least, consider using any parts of the search to filter the data in SQL BEFORE you pull it down to Excel, that will reduce the amount of data.

Comment: Aaron comment was exactly what i wanted. Thank you for your answer. I should point out i was never going to perform the search within the file produced (be it excel or some other).  Question really was how I select a bunch of a rows in some form of order via unique value and copy them into another. that's it. I had added a new column before with the number correct number value for each.